# Why passing param name is mandatory for RestTemplate in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

I implemented api

```
https://theysaidso.com/api/#qod
```

using spring rest template. My question is if I make url like below it works. But if I remove the param name from the bracket, it doesnt and returns error. Any idea? Thanks!

This works :

```
QuoteResponse quoteResponse=    
this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://quotes.rest/qod.json?category=
{param}", QuoteResponse.class, category);
```

this doesn't

```
QuoteResponse quoteResponse=    
this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://quotes.rest/qod.json?category={}", 
QuoteResponse.class, category);
```

I imagine that both translates to below (taking value passes as inspire for category string

```
"http://quotes.rest/qod.json?category=inspire"
```

Update(added more code): Controller

```
@Autowired
QuoteService quoteService;

@RequestMapping(value="/ws/quote/daily", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Quote> getDailyQuote(@RequestParam(required=false) String category){
    Quote quote = quoteService.getDaily(category);
    if(quote==null)
        return new ResponseEntity<Quote>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    return new ResponseEntity<Quote>(quote,HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

QuoteService.getDaily

```
@Override
public Quote getDaily(String category){
    if(category==null || category.isEmpty())
        category=QuoteService.CATEGORY_INSPIRATIONAL;
    QuoteResponse quoteResponse=
            this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://quotes.rest/qod.json?category={cat}", 
                    QuoteResponse.class, category);


    return quoteResponse.getContents().getQuotes()[0];      
}
```

Comment: pasting controller code help us to look into this.

Comment: @Lovababu added

Comment: since you have "required=false", spring wont force you to pass the query param. and category={any_name}, here *{any_name}* is just a place holder for RestTemplate, it replace this placeholder with supplied uriVariable before making actual rest call.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://quotes.rest/qod.json?category=
{param}", QuoteResponse.class, category);
```

When you make request like this, it means you are passing **PathVariable** into Controller which handeled by `@PathVariable` annotation in the controller's argument.

PathVariable are **required** in order to get your work done if controller has `@PathVariable` on it.

```
restTemplate.getForObject("http://quotes.rest/qod.json?category={}", 
QuoteResponse.class, category);
```

When you make request like this, **you are not sending any PathVariable with your request which is required here, so does not work and throws [MissingPathVariableException](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/MissingPathVariableException.html)**

Comment: @Thanks! I assume you meant RequestParameter not PathVariable, because to my understanding path variable would have been like /quotes.rest/qod.json/{cat} and //quotes.rest/qod.json?category={cat} is for request param.

but to this one question, RequestParam is supposed to have a name, right? whereas it works for any name passed, i.e.
this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://quotes.rest/qod.json?category=
{param}", QuoteResponse.class, category).. works.. and .this also works.
this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://quotes.rest/qod.json?category=
{param12345}", QuoteResponse.class, category)